# How can a case statement be created from a API Results from with the struct? | Swift

Tags: swift

So I have the following stuct that is used for decoding the API response. Depending on the value that comes through for carrier I would like to determine the color scheme for examples:

```
struct Info: Codable {
    var code: String
    var message: String
    var data: DataClass?
    
    struct DataClass: Codable {
        var carrier_id: String
        var number: String
   }
}


struct ColorOptions: Identifiable {
    let foreground: Color
    let background: Color
}
```

Each time `carrier_id` is equal to T-Mobile I would like to pre-determine the foreground to be black and the background color to pink.

If the `carrier_id` is equal to ATT like to pre-determine the foreground to be black and the background color to blue.

Where can this case statement for colors be put within the the DataClass struct?

Comment: What are those colors used for, in the UI? It’s not obvious what you mean with foreground and background colors here even if one could make an educated guess. If the carrier id can be one of a limited number of possibilities then you could consider using an enum for it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes it is for the UI used within a ListView, can you please show an example of what this enum would look like to account for both back and fore ground colors

Comment: No the enum was primarily for the carriers but you could add a computed property that returned foreground/background color for each carrier using a switch statement

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So essentially what the 1 response is doing below?

Comment: Well I wouldn’t add UI specific code to my model types but sure one could use a dictionary as well.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do you mind showing an example of your ideal method? I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a [String:ColorOptions] dictionary with the possible options: eg:

```
let colorScheme =[
"T-Mobile" : ColorOptions(foreground: .black, background: .pink),
"ATT" : ColorOptions(foreground: .black, background: .blue)]
```

then you can do the following in DataClass :

```
struct DataClass : Codable {
     var carrier_id: String
     var number: String
     lazy var color_scheme = colorScheme[carrier_id] ?? ColorOptions(foreground: .black, background: .white)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to also include a default color scheme for a scenario that does not match what is in the colorScheme for example

Comment: that's exactly what the code above would do, if there's no match it provides a default of black foreground with white background. Also as Joakim mentioned, maybe it's a good idea not to add UI-specific code in the model type, but you can use the same logic in your view to get hold of the color scheme.